# 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment occur when defined __getattribute__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newcomer to Python. Recently, I'v been reading about the builtin method of Python class. Here is the problem:

```
class Test:
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key] = value

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        T = Test()
        setattr(T, 'xx', 33)
        print(getattr(T, 'xx'))
```

When I run this script, I got error message:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

But when I removed the `__getattribute__` method, everything worked fine.
I have no idea about how this happened. Why does `__getattribute__` method affect the data type of my object `T`?

Comment: It works fine in python 2.  But the error happens in Python 3!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `__getattribute__` method is always called when you try to get an attribute of an object:

```
t=Test()
print(t.attribute)
```

But in you `__setattr__` method you are using `__getattribute__`:

```
def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    self.__dict__[key]=value  #__getattribute__("__dict__") is called
```

But **getattribute** returns None (`pass` does nothing so it returns None by default)
And then you tried to assign an item to None, but that doesn't work, so there is an exception.
I hope everything is clear now

Greetings, MrP01 :)

Comment: Note: item assignment means `obj [key] = value`, but setattr means `obj.key = value`

Answer (score 0):

You are overridding the default `__getattribute__` method. `pass` inside the definition of your method will return None.

So therefore when `getattr(T, 'xx')` is called internally your overrided method is called which returns `None`

Comment: But the exception occur when execute `setattr(T, 'xx', 33)`, haven't reach the line`print(getattr(T, 'xx'))`

Comment: Yes, because you are overrided method is returning None. Remove that method to avoid exception.